# does C++ have spread operator?

Tags: c++, arrays, spread-syntax

can you do this in C++:

```
vector<int> v1={1,2}, v2={3,4};
vector<int> v3={...v1, ...v2, 5};
//v3 = {1,2,3,4,5}
```

What is the simplest way to do this with C++ ?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249341/discussion-on-question-by-ludovic-aubert-does-c-have-spread-operator).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No spread operator in C++.

Probably the simplest way would be a sequence of `insert`s

```
std::vector<int> v3;
v3.insert(v3.end(), v1.begin(), v1.end());
v3.insert(v3.end(), v2.begin(), v2.end());
v3.insert(v3.end(), 5);
```

Various range libraries have a `concat` function

```
auto v3 = ranges::views::concat(v1, v2, { 5 }) | 
          ranges::views::join | 
          ranges::views::to<vector>;
```

C++23 or ranges::v3. Still more verbose than spread operator.

Answer (score 6):

I would implement it with a helper function like this. Online demo here : https://onlinegdb.com/AnA3GkbQL
This template code kind of writes out all the individual push_backs and inserts needed to get the final result (at compile time).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

namespace details
{
    template<typename type_t, typename arg_t, typename... args_t>
    auto make_spread_impl(std::vector<type_t>& values, const arg_t& arg, const args_t&... args)
    {
        // check if template argument is a value or a std::vector of values.
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<arg_t, type_t>)
        {
            // single value
            values.push_back(arg);
        }
        else
        {
            // vector of values
            static_assert(std::is_same_v<std::vector<type_t>, arg_t>);

            // append values to end
            values.insert(values.end(), arg.begin(), arg.end());
        }

        // continue recursion
        if constexpr (sizeof...(args_t) > 0)
        {
            return make_spread_impl(values, args...);
        }

        // recursion end condition
        return values;
    }
}

template<typename type_t, typename... args_t>
auto make_spread(const args_t&... args)
{

    // one argument return a vector of values.
    if constexpr (sizeof...(args) == 1ul)
    {
        return std::vector<type_t>{args...};
    }
    
    // otherwise recurse
    std::vector<type_t> values;
    details::make_spread_impl(values, args...);
    return values;
}



int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v1{ 1,2,3 };
    std::vector<int> v2{ 5,6,7 };

    auto result = make_spread<int>(v1, 4, v2, 8);

    for (const auto& value : result)
    {
        std::cout << value << " ";
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think this is as close as we can get to what OP wants.

Comment: Library approach, the implementation may not be (directly) clear, but the usage should be. So I will be happy to answer any questions that arise.

Comment: When you change `static_assert(std::is_same_v<std::vector<type_t>, arg_t>);` to `static_assert(std::is_same_v<type_t, typename arg_t::value_type>);` it would also accept other containers.

Comment: @mch true and a good addition, but I wanted to keep the solution kind of focused. (To make it a true library function I would also have to add unit tests).

Comment: oops, was just looking at `impl`

Comment: @Caleth NP, I have these kinds of moments all the time :)

Comment: I'd be tempted to do one arg in `impl`, and `details::make_spread_impl(values, args)...;`, which gets rid of a whole lot of `if`s

Comment: @Caleth Be my guest this was "naive" first implementation :)

Comment: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b838a1133a316abe

Comment: AH nice C20-fied! I am so looking forward to my work moving over to C++20 compilers, I do dabble around with it at home. But mostly C++17 is still my daily driver. But I reaaly like how C++20 cleans up meta programming. And the use of the fold expression, I need to think more often of using that.

Comment: ofcourse the comment line : `// check if template argument is a value or a std::vector of values.` should then read check if type has a push_back method